# Python unit test - NameError: name 'upper' is not defined

Tags: python, unit-testing, nameerror

Using Python 3.x. When running the test case for the following code, I get the error - `NameError: name 'upper' is not defined`. I am attaching the file to test, the `File_P_third` file where is the code, and the unit test file `test_upper`.

File `File_P_third`:

```
def upper_text(text):
    return text.upper()
```

File `test_upper`:

```
import unittest
import File_P_third


class TestUpper(unittest.TestCase):
    """docstring for ClassName"""
    def test_one_word(self):
        text = 'hello!'
        result = upper.upper_text(text)
        self.assertEqual(result, 'HELLO!')
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

My cmd`s exit text:

```
D:\Дохуя программист\Projects>python test_upper.py
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_one_word (__main__.TestUpper)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_upper.py", line 9, in test_one_word
    result = upper.upper_text(text)
NameError: name 'upper' is not defined

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

All files is in one directory and I still cant understand why is doesnt work. Can`t search the same problem in internet((

Comment: Well, yeah. `upper` isn't defined. What was `upper` supposed to be in `upper.upper_text(text)`?

Comment: Is your test_upper file complete? You should use File_P_third. upper_text() or from File_P_third import upper_text and then upper_text(text)

Comment: Replace `upper.upper_text(text)` with `File_P_third.upper_text(text)` and it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `import File_P_third` with `from File_P_third import upper_text`. Call your function this way `result = upper_text(text)`. Also make sure, both files File_P_third.py and test_upper.py are in the same directory.

Below you'll find the complete code for your file File_P_third.py:

```
import unittest
from File_P_third import upper_text


class TestUpper(unittest.TestCase):
    """docstring for ClassName"""
    def test_one_word(self):
        text = 'hello!'
        result = upper_text(text)
        self.assertEqual(result, 'HELLO!')
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to transform 'hello' to upper case, the function to do so in python is string.upper()
i takes no parameter see below:

```
test='hello'
up=test.upper()
print(up)
# prints HELLO
```